# Visual Studio 2017 cannot connect to WSL says Username and Password are wrong

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cross-compiling

I followed this tutorial [from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/08/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/). I created my WSL username and password, installed all the necessary applications, and started the SSH service. The problem lies when I go to connect to it from Visual Studio in the `Tools > Options > Cross Platform > Connection Manager` menu.

I follow the instructions:

- Host Name = localhost
- Port = 22
- User name = User name I created for WSL
- Authentication Type = Password
- Password = Password I created for WSL user name.

When I do this, it says my user name or password is incorrect. But I know they are correct. I can't post images to show it because my reputation is not at 10 yet but it highlights the username and password bar in red and says `Authentication failure. Please make sure credentials are correct.`

I know I can connect to devices because I tried connecting to my Raspberry Pi. Whenever I try and debug anything on that it gives me a segmentation fault. But that's another question for another day.

Any ideas as to why I can't connect to my WSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using the information in this link, I was able to solve the issue.](https://superuser.com/questions/1123552/how-to-ssh-into-wsl) Just had to change the port from 22 into another port.

Do:
`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Change:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

to

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 2222
```

Assuming you followed everything else in the WSL set-up tutorial from Microsoft. This will work.

According to @fnt in that link, port 22 doesn't work because Microsoft has SSH Server Broker running on that port.

Comment: thanks for the solution.save my time.really appreciated.

Comment: You saved my day